# Is a feature administrator able to manage only the features within an application?

Tags: 70-667, exams

I found two different answers on a SharePoint questions

You need to ensure that a user named User1 is able to manage only the features within an application.

What should you do?

A: Configure User1 within the Secure Store Server as an administrator

B: Add User1 as feature administrator within the particular site collections that require management of non farm administrators?

Which one is correct :S Would be awesome if you could explain to!

note: Im using visual certexam manager and both answers are correct on different dumps :S